# How can I change the volume of a sound?

Tags: android

I'm new to android studio and I'm developing an app. 
I want to add a mp3 sound every time I click a button, I know how to do this. And each time I click the button, I want to increase/decrease the sound by 5/10 dB.
Is there any easy way to do this by writing a code?

Answer (score 0):

it will cost a lot cpu usage... increase the sound volume of those mp3 using some sound editing software like audacity and then use those in your app.

Comment: see https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic
Lib can speed up / slow down speech, but besides this it allows to increase loudness too. see Sonic.java for more functionality